# How to set "Process Priority" and "Process Affinity" on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, cpu, process, task-manager

On Windows 7 everything we must do to set

**"Process Priority"(to Low \ Below Normal \ Normal \ Above Normal \ High \ Realtime)**

or to set

**"Process Affinity"(to choose wich processor core would run on specifc process)**

was opening [Windows Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager), click on "Processes", right-click on a process and both options were showed and avaiable to easily set:

[image]

Nowadays, with Windows 8 I can't find it anymore...

1. **Is this still avaiable?**
2. **If so, how could I do that?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is still avaiable, but you can't access these configurations as the same way we did in the past(with Windows 7). It is still acessible via [Windows 8 Task Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20151106093728/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/10/13/the-windows-8-task-manager.aspx) , but not on the same place(on Processes tab).

Now, first of all, after opening the Task Manager(with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) you must click on "More Details" to see details of the running tasks:

[image]

Then you must go to the "Details" tab(and not to the "Processes" anymore as we usually did on windows 7). After that, right-click on the process "Name" that you want to set priority or affinity, then go to "Set Priority" or "Set Affinity" and set it as you may want:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can still use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to control priority and affinity:

[image]

Comment: That is not part of windows though (unless that changed as well)

Comment: @soandos: That is correct. It's still a third-party tool which is not included with Windows 8 (at least to my understanding).

Comment: @soandos - While not included with Windows its still written by Microsoft.